Out-of-Phase Transverse and Longitudinal Components of the EM Field in a Step-Index Optical Fiber?
I'm trying to get a little bit of intuition, or even mathematically understand, the following statement:

Whenever a fiber is twisted, the resulting shear stress couples the longitudinal electric field of one mode with the transverse field of the orthogonal mode. Because these field components are $\pi$/2 out of phase, ...

(This specific quote comes from (Rashleigh, 1983), with other papers including the one cited by this one basically stating the same thing without justification, presumably because it's "elementary.")
The part I'm interested in is bolded: what I'm trying to understand is why the longitudinal electric field of one of the two orthogonally polarized modes and the transverse field of the other orthogonal mode are $\pi$/2 out of phase. It's not clear to me from Maxwell's equations as worked out e.g. in these notes. (Incidentally, these notes show that the longitudinal components of the two modes are $\pi$/2 out of phase, but without an additional relation to the transverse components that isn't enough.)
I'd really like an intuitive understanding, but even a mathematical explanation would be great.
